# No supported Visual C/C++ compiler found. Check your installation of Visual C/C++

Tags: matlab, visual-c++, deployment, simulink

I am using Matlab R2013a. The problem appears when I try to use `Simulink Coder` to generate `Visual C++` code.

I've got this error even though I have `Visual Studio 2013` installed on my computer already. When I look at list of programs that are installed on my computer I see Visual C++ 2008, 2010 and 2012. When I type the command `mex -setup` Matlab just can see a compiler LCC. But I need a Visual C++ compiler (which , technically, I already have) seen by Matlab.

How can I do that? Isn't `mex -setup` the right code?

Comment: If you are asking Visual Stuido, it is Ultimate.

Comment: Assuming you have MATLAB R2014a because they didn't add support for VC++ 2013 [until R2014a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html).

Comment: I use Matlab R2013a . I will add this information to my post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need MATLAB R2014a since support for Visual C++ 2013 was not added [until MATLAB R2014a](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html).

As a workaround, you can use [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44408-matlab-mex-support-for-visual-studio-2013-and-mbuild) or [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44051-visual-studio-2013-support-for-matlab-compiler-toolbox-x64) FileExchange submission to add support for building MEX files using Visual C++ 2013 with earlier MATLAB version.

Comment: The answer is probably the solution. The problem is these are for Windows x64 but I use x86.

Comment: Their mexopts files are just modified versions of the VS 2012 mexopts files.  You can do something similar.